# Rails: Passing API Keys to the Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I'm working on integrating the Twilio API into my Rails app. I followed the tutorial [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/10/twilio-on-rails-part-2-rails-4-app-sending-sms-mms.html), but I'm running into an issue getting the API keys into the controller. They recommend using ENV variables, however, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to do this (only been using Rails for a few weeks).

So I guess I have two questions:

- What is the best/easiest way to use ENV variables in an development/local environment?
- If I hardcode the values into the secrets.yml file, shouldn't that work? I understand this isn't ideal for security, but for testing, would it work or would they need to be initialized somehow?

**Error:**

```
ArgumentError in NotificationsController#notify - Account SID and auth token are required
```

**notifications_controller.rb**

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def notify
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.secrets.twilio_account_sid, Rails.application.secrets.twilio_auth_token
    message = client.messages.create from: '+18588779747', to: '+18583821931', body: 'First ever MyMedy notifcation test.'
    render plain: message.status
  end

end
```

**secrets.yml**

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  twilio_account_sid: <%= ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"] %>
  twilio_auth_token: <%= ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"] %>

test:

production:
  secret_key_base: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  twilio_account_sid: <%= ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"] %>
  twilio_auth_token: <%= ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"] %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio.

There are a number of ways to set `ENV` variables in a Rails application. Simplest is to run the following couple of lines in the terminal window in which you are running your `rails server` command

```
export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=ACXXXXX
export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=YYYYYY
```

Then, for the life of that window, those environment variables will be set.

For a more permanent solution, you could add those couple of lines to your `~/.bash_profile`.

```
export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=ACXXXXX
export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=YYYYYY
```

and then `source ~/.bash_profile` which will load the variables into your current terminal window and then any other terminal window you open.

There are also some gems that could help. Check out [envyable](https://github.com/philnash/envyable), [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) or [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) which can all be used to set `ENV` variables in your application on an app by app basis.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking to get the controller action working feel free to paste the values directly in to eliminate one more dependency. After you are sure it is working then move it to into a secrets.yml or application.yml file.

On a side note, when using rails its best to stick to convention on RESTful actions. Instead of using this:

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def notify
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.secrets.twilio_account_sid, Rails.application.secrets.twilio_auth_token
    message = client.messages.create from: '+18588779747', to: '+18583821931', body: 'First ever MyMedy notifcation test.'
    render plain: message.status
  end

end
```

You might want to use this:

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.secrets.twilio_account_sid, Rails.application.secrets.twilio_auth_token
    message = client.messages.create from: '+18588779747', to: '+18583821931', body: 'First ever MyMedy notifcation test.'
    render plain: message.status
  end

end
```

You might want to also look to move some of these methods into a more clean Model method, or even a [service object](https://netguru.co/blog/service-objects-in-rails-will-help).